# Scroll two lists separated in a row inside a column

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, scroll

I have two lists side by side in a row and I would like to make those lists scrollable in vertical individually.

The original app is in my github: https://github.com/GabrielDangelo21/kleyte-bibi/tree/main/lib

I did just an example of one of the lists but I have two like this one:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Expanded(
    flex: 1,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: transactions.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                final tr = transactions[index];
                return LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (ctx, constraints) {
                    return Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.37,
                          child: Text(
                            'test',
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.1,
                          child: Text(
                            'test',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

And my main.dart is with this scaffold

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Transaction> transactionKleyte = [

  ];
  List<Transaction> transactionBibi = [

  ];

return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: availableHeight * 0.07,
              child: Text('test',),
            ),
            Container(
              height: availableHeight * 0.07,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Text('test'),
                  Text('Test'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: availableHeight * 0.86,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  TransactionListKleyte(
                    transactionKleyte,
                  ),
                  TransactionListBibi(
                    transactionBibi,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Like I said, the original code is in my github because I have tried to put here but it is not possible because it says that is almost only code.

Thanks in advance.